# Using BATCH to clean up file names to name full path

Tags: batch-file, automation

All the information is located in a text file. I would like to go from this:

```
/var/www/xxx/video_folder_1:
New folder
New folder - Copy
New folder - Copy (10)
New folder - Copy (10) - Copy
New folder - Copy (10) - Copy - Copy
New folder - Copy (11)

/var/www/xxx/video_folder_2:
cideo.mp4
sadasd
```

To this:

> ```
> /var/www/xxx/video_folder_1/New folder
> /var/www/xxx/video_folder_1/New folder - Copy
> /var/www/xxx/video_folder_1/New folder - Copy (10)
> /var/www/xxx/video_folder_1/New folder - Copy (10) - Copy
> /var/www/xxx/video_folder_1/New folder - Copy (10) - Copy - Copy
> /var/www/xxx/video_folder_1/New folder - Copy (11)/
> /var/www/xxx/video_folder_2/cideo.mp4
> /var/www/xxx/video_folder_2/sadasd
> ```

To be honest, I have NOT idea how to approach this as this is way beyond my batch skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if "!line:~0,1!" equ "/" (
      set "header=%%a"
   ) else (
      echo !header:~0,-1!/%%a
   )
)
```

Comment: This looks great, how would I echo it out into a text file please? Let us say, testnew.txt.  Ahhh. got it  'echo !header:~0,-1!/%%a>>c:\newtest.txt'

Comment: I would like to ask if it is possible to delete any lines with have .MP4, however should I create a new post.